# How to make typing animation for every line in an order with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation, sass, keyframe

```html
<div class='screen'>
  <div class='text-container'>
    <p class='text'>A problem has been detected and system has been shut down to prevent damage to your computer.
    </p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL</p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your computer.</p>
    <p class='text'>If this screen appears again, follow these steps:</p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>Check to make sure any new hardware or soFtware is properly installed.</p>
    <p class='text'>If this is a new installation,</p>
    <p class='text'>ask your hardware or soFtware manufacturer for any system updates you might need.</p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware or soFtware.</p>
    <p class='text'>Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.</p>
    <p class='text'>If you need to use Safe Mode to remove or disable components, restart your computer.</p>
    <p class='text'>press F8 to select Advanced Startup options, and then select Safe Mode.</p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>Technical information:</p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>*** STOP: 0x0000000A /0x0000000000004A,</p>
    <p class='text'>0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000001, 0xFFFFF80002B37ABF</p>
    <br />
    <p class='text'>Collecting data for crash dump ...</p>
    <p class='text'>Initializing disk for crash dump ...</p>
    <p class='text'>Beginning dump of physical memory.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```scss
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}

div.screen {
    background-color: #032f7c;

    div.text-container {
      padding: 20px;
      
      p.text {
        font-family: monospace;
        color: #ebf6ff;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px;
        animation: typing 5s steps(90, end);
      }
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is here showing the text to the user with a typing animation that line by line, one after the other, from top to bottom. I tried many things but I couldn't find a solution other than defining a different `keyframe` for each `p.text` element. In this way my code turns into spaghetti because there are 17 `p.text` element. How do I do?

Here is this problem's codepen link : https://codepen.io/mehmetguduk/pen/RwJqzpN

Comment: Does this help? https://youtu.be/w1nhwUGsG6M

Comment: A little bit of JavaScript would give you an accurate rendition as it can know exactly when an animation ends. Is using JS acceptable?

Comment: It would be also acceptable but I dont want you to spend your time because answer that comes from @tobimori solved my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a delay manually to each line. With SCSS, an example code snippet to do so is using a `@for` loop and then multiplying the index with the duration of the animation.

```
    @for $i from 0 through 20 {
      p.text:nth-of-type(#{$i + 1}) {
        animation-delay: #{$i * 4}s;
      }
    }
```

This, of course, needs some additional tweaking for the perfect timing, but should give you a general idea of how to solve this.

Make sure, your animation state is also set to `both`, so the text is already hidden in the beginning and stays visible after the end of the animation.

### Edit:

You can also use JavaScript to set the animation-delay, like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('p.text').forEach((el, i) => el.style.animationDelay = `${i * 5}s`)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Updating p.text part of my scss solved my problem. But what if I turn this to an infinite animation. Then what should i do?

Comment: At this point, you'll need to use JavaScript to set the delay. I edited my solution to include an example of how you could solve this.